# MS.Excel- Is it possible to password protect one or two columns in an excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-protection

I have an excel file which would be available on a shared drive. I want the users to be able to access all columns except one or two columns. Except the two columns which are protected all other columns should be editable.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried "Protect Cells"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select a whole column, then go to Format/Cells and then the protection tab, and tick to protect them. Then go to Tools, protection and protect sheet to apply protection.

Answer (score 3):

it is possible to protect the sheet, then allow certain ranges to be editable under tools->protection

Answer (score 1):

For windows 7 Office 2010 :
Select All Collumn which you DONT want to lock. then go to formate-protection-and remove tick mark of "Lock". then go to Review and click on Protect sheet. Tick mark the option which actions you want to lock and then set the password. reconfirm the password and press ok.